# Mantis Bug tracker API integration?

Tags: php, api, soap, bug-tracking, mantis

I have just installed the Mantis bug tracker to use together with Eclipse IDE and have started too found out the advantages of it. Really great.

Since Eclipse communicates with Mantis through an PHP soap API, I wonder if there's some documentation available on how I can myself make calls, from my PHP application to the API to add new bugs and get statuses of existing ones.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As you solved your problem, but it took a lot of time, any chance in posting the code to get the status?  Maybe even to add a bug?

Comment: @StevenScott I do not have access to that codebase any longer I'm afraid :(

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I was able to sort it out myself while using php soapCall functions and going through the code, step by step. Took really long time, but It worked out at least...

Comment: It's better to explain how did you solve your issue, any links to documentation have you found?

Answer (score 44):

I too was looking for an answer to this and thought I'd add my findings to this question so I can find them again later (and hopefully they're of use to someone else too)

The URL of the SOAP API is `$(MANTIS_URI)/api/soap/mantisconnect.php` (e.g. if your Mantis is usually accessed at `http://localhost/mantis/` then go to `http://localhost/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php`)

It uses NuSOAP which means that if you point your web browser at that URL you get HTML documentation of the web service; most of the actions seem to have sensible names and a one-line description of what it does. The WSDL can be downloaded at `$(MANTIS_URI)/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl` and, because I'm using C#, running `wsdl.exe` on that URL gives me a basic strongly-typed client library for the service that seems pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Hi Dave

Thanks a lot for your answer. Yep - mantisconnect.php does the magic. However I didn't know about the documentation, guessing that it would have been eeasier with it :)

Comment: Every API project I did have such documentation on api endpoint